Joining Strings into final String when the items are in StringBuilder
I have read about the StringBuilder API and StringJoiner API and String.join but not sure if I have items in StringBuilder instance, which call to use to do a join with a delimiter of choice. I do not want to manually iterate and do it(error prone to some degree)
The below returns result without delimiter:
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.append("s1");
sb.append("s2");
String str2 = String.join("::",sb);
System.out.println(str2);

Above gives the output as s1s2. And I am not sure why?

Note that the 2nd+ parameter(s) of join is a varargs parameter and so you've provided only one string to join.  For example String.join("::","s1","s2") would produce s1::s2.  Seems you cannot get there with your StringBuilder approach.

This is impossible. A StringBuilder does not maintain separate elements that can be joined later. Element boundaries are already lost by the time you try to call String.join.
You need to use a StringJoiner from the start, or if you're really forced to use a StringBuilder for some reason, you will need to add separators between items manually.

tl;dr
Did you expect a result of s1::s2?
Then you need to study the documentation to learn that StringBuilder is a single piece of text, not a collection of multiple pieces of text.
Try:
String.join( "::" , List.of( "s1" , "s2" ) )


s1::s2

Details
You have misunderstood both StringBuilder class and String.join method.
StringBuilder
The StringBuilder class does not represent a collection of text parts.
StringBuilder  represents one single piece of text. Every time you call append, the current content is combined with the passed text to make a new piece of text that becomes the new content. There is no history of the appended parts; a StringBuilder object has just a single piece of text.
String.join
The String.join method is intended to receive multiple pieces of text. The first argument is the delimiter to be used between the various pieces of text being joined. After the first argument, you should either:

Pass multiple pieces of text (not just one piece), or
Pass an Iterable< ? extends CharSequence > such as a a List of String objects.

So, if we pass two pieces of text such as "dog" & "cat" with a delimiter of "::", we get dog::cat.
String result = String.join( "::" , "dog" , "cat" ) ;


dog::cat

Joining a singe piece of text, makes no sense
But you only passed two arguments, the delimiter and a single piece of text. With only a single piece of text, there is no use for the delimiter.
String result = String.join( "::" , "dog" ) ;


dog

So there really is no point to writing code like that example, with just "dog" but no other pieces of text.
Your code:
String str2 = String.join("::",sb);

… uses String.join method where you can pass objects of any type that implements the CharSequence interface. Both String & StringBuilder implement CharSequence. So you passing a StringBuilder argument is legal, just like our example above passing "dog" is legal.
But like our example above passing just "dog", your code here really does not make sense. Your original pieces of text "s1" & "s2" have already been combined within your StringBuilder object. So you passing just "sb" has the same result as if you had written:
String str2 = String.join("::","s1s2");

The result is a string of four characters:

s1s2

Apparently you expected a result of s1::s2. But your expectation would be incorrect.
As always, programming by documentation is better than programming by intuition. To quote the very first sentence of the Javadoc for StringBuilder says:

A mutable sequence of characters.

That documentation does not say anything about being a collection of multiple pieces of text.
Joining a collection of pieces of text
If you want a collection of multiple pieces of text, use an implementation of SequencedCollection like a List or a SequencedSet. Technically, you need a Iterable< ? extends CharSequence >.
SequencedCollection < String > piecesOfText = new ArrayList <>( );
piecesOfText.add( "s1" );
piecesOfText.add( "s2" );
String result = String.join( "::" , piecesOfText );
System.out.println( result );


s1::s2

Or, more briefly:
String result = String.join( "::" , List.of( "s1" , "s2" ) );
System.out.println( result );

Same result.

s1::s2


You can also do it using streams.  The reason I mention this is that it provides an option to include prefixes and suffixes.
Here are some examples.
Here is what you were trying to do.
String str3 = Stream.of("s1","s2").collect(Collectors.joining("::"));
System.out.println(str3);

prints
s1::s2

Here the prefix/suffix strings are provided.
String str3 = Stream.of("s1","s2").collect(Collectors.joining("::", "[", "]"));
System.out.println(str3);

prints
[s1::s2]

And you can also use arrays and lists.  Here is an array example.  For a list it would just be list.stream()...";
String[] strs = {"s1", "s2"};
String str3 = Arrays.stream(strs).collect(Collectors.joining("::", "[", "]"));
System.out.println(str3);

prints
[s1::s2]


The issue you're encountering is due to a misunderstanding of how StringBuilder and String.join() work together. The StringBuilder class doesn't keep track of individual elements; it simply appends characters to create a single continuous sequence. When you call sb.append("s1"); sb.append("s2");, the StringBuilder contains "s1s2" as one string, not as separate elements.
When you pass sb to String.join("::", sb);, it's not joining multiple strings with the delimiter "::" because StringBuilder isn't an array or a collection of strings. Instead, it's treated as a single CharSequence, so no joining occurs, and the delimiter isn't inserted.
To achieve the desired output of "s1::s2", consider the following alternatives:
1. Use a List to collect your strings and then join them:
List<String> items = new ArrayList<>();
items.add("s1");
items.add("s2");
String result = String.join("::", items);
System.out.println(result); // Outputs: s1::s2

2. Use StringJoiner:
StringJoiner sj = new StringJoiner("::");
sj.add("s1");
sj.add("s2");
String result = sj.toString();
System.out.println(result); // Outputs: s1::s2

3. Manually append the delimiter using StringBuilder:
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.append("s1").append("::").append("s2");
String result = sb.toString();
System.out.println(result); // Outputs: s1::s2

Explanation:

Option 1: Collecting the strings in a List allows you to use String.join() effectively, as it can iterate over the collection and insert the delimiter between elements.
Option 2: StringJoiner is designed specifically for joining strings with a delimiter without the need to manage separators manually.
Option 3: If you prefer to use StringBuilder, you need to append the delimiter yourself between the strings since StringBuilder doesn't handle delimiters automatically.

Why Your Original Code Doesn't Work:
Your original code doesn't insert the delimiter because String.join("::", sb); is not used correctly. String.join() expects a delimiter and an array or an Iterable of CharSequence instances (like a List of String objects). Since StringBuilder doesn't implement Iterable<CharSequence>, and it represents a single sequence of characters, the method doesn't have multiple elements to join, so the delimiter isn't applied.
Correct Usage of String.join():
If you have an array or a collection of strings, you can use String.join() like this:
String[] strings = {"s1", "s2"};
String result = String.join("::", strings);
System.out.println(result); // Outputs: s1::s2

Conclusion:
To insert delimiters between strings, you need to use a data structure that holds individual elements, like a List or an array, and then use String.join() or StringJoiner. If you're using StringBuilder, you'll have to manually append the delimiter between the strings.
